# Can I alter nautilus file manager through config files?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

I thought of a possibly more convienient way to alter my home directory, and would like to know if I could alter the directories in the side bar of the file manager or if I would have to recompile it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe in more detail what exactly you would like to achieve

Comment: Possible to some extent. What exactly do you want to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter **some** of the folders in the left pane of the file manager. To add a folder, just drag it into the lower third of the left pane. To remove, or arrange folders, go to the Bookmarks menu and choose Bookmarks.